# Perspective + montage with overlap of multiple images at the command-line

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have a collection (of variable size) of rectangular images (frames extracted from a source video file with `ffmpeg`), and am trying to find a way to automatically generate a "filmstrip" at the command line, ideally one in which each image is rotated to give it a perspective, and then partly overlayed with the previous one.

The output would be something like this (with transparent background)
[image]

(Note: Numbers in the corner would be a plus...)

I imagine ImageMagick has the tools for this, but so far I've not found any obvious way of achieving this...

Any pointer?

Comment: Pointer to self: https://imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#overlap

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that worked quite nicely for me:

````
  -virtual-pixel transparent +distort Perspective '0,0 0,0 0,110 0,110 200,0 100,20 200,110 100,80' \
  -gravity South -background transparent -splice 0x15  \
  -font Arial -pointsize 12 -gravity southwest -annotate +2+0 "%[p]" \
  miff:- | \
  montage -geometry 100x\>-20+2 -tile x1 -background none - montage_test.png```

![montage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezplh.png)
````